# Android ContentResolver.getType is not ready when app starts

Tags: android

I'm getting an issue where `ContentResolver.getType` is not ready when the app starts.
However, putting a delay of 1s, will make it ready.

Code:

```
        String mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri); // returns null

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String mimeType2 = contentResolver.getType(uri); // returns correct mime type
```

Note this only happens on app startup.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.